# Testing out Protractor interactively

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to run the protractor interactively to test out the elments

I start the selenium server by

```
wedriver-manager start
```

Then I go to protractor root directory

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
```

and type the following command

```
"./bin/elementexplorer.js" http://some_server/someApp
```

I get following errors

```
Script
Line : 1
Char : 1
Error : Invalid Character
Code : 800A03F6
Source : MS JScript compliation error
```

At line of elementexplorer.js is the following line

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem too.  After you enter your protractor root directory, try entering the command

```
node bin\elementexplorer.js http://some_server/someApp
```

Make sure the node command is in your PATH environment variable so that it's recognized as a valid command.  #!/usr/bin/env node is generally something you see on Unix-based systems, so in this case you need to put "node" in front to tell Windows to use Node.js.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I was also confused about this unix commands in the script file. I have a very little(or no) knowledge of Node.js

Comment: +1 Thanks!. This should be added to the Protractor documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try leaving the quotes of the path

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307#issuecomment-488470306

node 10+ which has repl-await (so you can just await in the console)

Special interactive debug spec - interactive.e2e.ts

```
import { LoginPage } from './src/pages/login.po';
import { AppPage } from './src/pages/app.po';
import { SwitchProfileSideSheet } from './src/side-sheets/switch-profile-side-sheet.po';
import { sel } from '../src/testing/get-component';

const login = new LoginPage();
const app = new AppPage();
const switchProfileSideSheet = new SwitchProfileSideSheet();

// add my own page objects to the global object so I can use them interactively.
global['sel'] = sel;
global['po'] = {
  login,
  app,
  switchProfileSideSheet,
};

(global as any).systemTestsDone = new Promise(function(_resolve, _reject) {
  global['finishInteractiveDebug'] = _resolve;
});

describe('TestHelper', () => {
  it('should provide a way to interactively run tests', async () => {
    await (global as any).systemTestsDone;
  });
});
```

package.json

```
"e2e-interactive": "node --experimental-repl-await --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor ./e2e/protractor.interactive.conf",
```

protractor.interactive.conf.js

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

// standard protractor config
const baseConfig = require('./protractor.conf');
const configCopy = Object.assign({}, baseConfig.config);

const oneDayInMilliSeconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
// set timeout to a huge number
// so it's not an issue when we pause in the debugger
configCopy.allScriptsTimeout = oneDayInMilliSeconds;
configCopy.jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval = oneDayInMilliSeconds;
// just load our interactive specs
configCopy.specs = ['./interactive.e2e.ts'];

console.log('interactive config', configCopy);
exports.config = configCopy;
```

now, i guess you just type `await element.all($('a')).get(0).getText()` on the console to get the text of the first anchor element. i still need to test this and come back and fix up my answer