# Error running gulp on Windows 10

Tags: gulp, windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 build `10576`(latest) and I get an error when running gulp from my project root folder(or anywhere). Here's a screenshot of the error: http://puu.sh/l3mLf/522a4e6dbe.png
Error message says "`invalid character`".
(I've installed gulp globally)
The very first line of `gulp.js` in the bin folder is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

I didn't have this problem before and I'd really want to get this sorted out. Thanks.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of errors. Instead, post the entire error, stack trace and all, as text in your question.

Comment: How can I trace it if it doesn't run gulp?

Comment: usually it's all just output to the console. in this case it's likely just the one line that specifies where the error occurred, (line 1 of gulp.js)

Comment: hmm... you're not running this from the console are you. How are you running it?

Comment: yes it's the first line but it's required for node, right?
!/usr/bin/env node
I am running it from console

Comment: In the one in my node_modules, yes, but not the gulpfile local to my project.

Comment: I assume this is yours? https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1361

Comment: My gulpfile is just fine and has worked till new windows update. yes it is

Comment: So your problem is with gulp itself, not related at all to your local project

Comment: so it's because of windows? because it (gulp) worked on an earlier build of windows 10

Comment: what has me doubting it being a general windows problem is the lack of an issue up until now, and the fact that it works in my version of windows 10.

Comment: alright, will try on my laptop after new update

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error when try running "node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js install".

I found the solution here at [Testing out Protractor interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387303/testing-out-protractor-interactively)

Just add "node" command in front of it will work. In my case "node node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js install"