# Bundling using webpack node moule

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have installed below webpack node module version in Win 10 system

```
npm install webpack@2.2.0-rc.3 --save
```

And when try to execute below command for bundling my sample .js file , it throws an error depicted in image.

```
.\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js index.js bundle.js
```

[image]

contents of index.js are

```
var app = document.getElementById('app');
app.innerHTML = '<p> Hi there </p>';
```

Any idea what needs to be done.

Comment: Post yout webpack config and babelrc please...

Comment: I have just started , my sample does not have both the files

Comment: Post your index.js, pplease

Comment: Could it be related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287666/gulp-run-fails-on-windows-error-message-microsoft-jscript-compilation-error

Comment: I followed what @Joe Clay has said, it is working now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `node` command to run JavaScript from the command line - just typing the filename like that will open it in whatever the associated program is for .js files on your system (in your case, Windows Script Host).

```
node .\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js index.js bundle.js
```

Alternatively, you could install Webpack globally, which will add the command to your PATH.

```
npm install webpack --global
webpack index.js bundle.js
```

Note that if you run the `webpack` command in a directory that has a local installation of Webpack (as you're doing here), [it'll use that version rather than the one you have installed globally](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/webpack.js#L9).