# Gulp not working with GitLab runner

Tags: powershell, gulp, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to get a GitLab runner to work on my laptop (Windows 10) but it does not execute the `gulp` commands, because `"gulp" is not recognized as a script`.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yaml`

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp-cli
  - npm install

cache:  
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build

building:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - onpremise
  script:   
    - gulp build
```

The relevant settings of my `config.toml`

```
executor = "shell"
shell = "powershell"
```

(*If I set shell to `"cmd"` then `gulp build` is not called at all.*)

And the output of my build job in GitLab

```
$ npm install -g gulp-cli
C:\USERS\_SYSTEM\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> 
C:\USERS\_SYSTEM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js
+ gulp-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 7.67s
$ npm install
up to date in 11.609s
$ gulp build
gulp : The term "gulp" is not recognized as cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: If you are using shel (powershell) as executor you should be able to run the same commands from a powershell console yourself. Try running gulp from one manually, if it is not recognised as a command, that is why the runner fails.

Comment: I can run gulp from my local powershell. But for reasons the runner does not have access.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment, so please forgive the guess. I'm suspecting $env:path for your working powershell session is different from the $env:path that your gitlab runner is getting.

You could confirm this by comparing the two by adding `$env:path.split(";")` to your build script and comparing the output to your working powershell session.

You can also run `get-command gulp | select source` in the session that works, to locate the gulp file *(on my server it's a .cmd file in a personal folder)* . You should then be able to add `$env:path = $env:path + ";C:\path\to\that\folder"` near the top of the build script to resolve the path issue I'm suspecting you have.

Additionally, you may need to install gulp globally if you have not already done so. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287770/7674011

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `- npm install --save-dev gulp` after `- npm install -g gulp-cli`.

Comment: Hello, gulp is part of my package.json,thus already getting installed by `npm install`

Comment: @Marc Hello, there is this thing I read about gulp sometimes not working on CI when you don't install it both globally and locally. I didn't put much thought to it but I tried it and it worked for me. Did you try?